# ForgotPassword hook in liferay

Tags: liferay, hook

I want to disable the password reminder question in my forgot password hook.

Answer (score -1):

Go through this link for difference http://liferay.wikispaces.com/Difference+between+Generic+Portlet+and+MVC+Portlet